# Make two arrays equal by reversing subarrays

Tags: arrays, dynamic-arrays

Today, I came across this problem on leetcode. I am not able to understand that how we achieve this target array from given array. I already solved this problem. My question is that how to find out that what set of subarray reversals will always form the target array. Does the order of elements does not matter?

### Problem

Given two integer arrays of equal length target and arr.
In one step, you can select any non-empty sub-array of arr and reverse it. You are allowed to make any number of steps.
Return True if you can make arr equal to target, or False otherwise.

#### Example

**Input:** target = [1,2,3,4], arr = [2,4,1,3]

**Output:** true

> Explanation

1. Reverse sub-array [2,4,1], arr becomes [1,4,2,3]
2. Reverse sub-array [4,2], arr becomes [1,2,4,3]
3. Reverse sub-array [4,3], arr becomes [1,2,3,4]
   There are multiple ways to convert arr to target, this is not the only way to do so.

[Link to problem on leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/make-two-arrays-equal-by-reversing-sub-arrays/).

#### My Solution

```
bool canBeEqual(vector<int>& target, vector<int>& arr) {
  sort(arr.begin() , arr.end());
  sort(target.begin() , target.end());
  return arr == target;
}
```

I just came up with this solution and it worked. But I couldn't prove why it worked. Does the order of elements does not matter? If both arrays have same elements with same frequency, will their be always a particular set of subarray reversal operations which would make it equal to target array? Why?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Problem is stated is such way that your mind directed to complex solution. Simplification of problem is this: check if one array is permutation of other array. This can be easily done in `O(n)` time complexity.

Comment: I recommend showing your best attempt at solving this problem. You might get it right. You might have A small mistake that we can show you how to fix quickly. You might be off by a country mile, but odds are good some one will spot where the attempt went wrong and help you deal with the root problem.

Comment: I solved it in 13 lines (counting all lines even empty to have nice formatting), so make sure you do not make this over complicated.

Comment: @MarekR I already solved this problem. My question is that how to find out that what set of subarray reversals will always form the target array. Does the order of elements does not matter?